# When a java class gets loaded, does it load the class only referenced (but not instantiated) in this class as well?

Tags: java, classloader

When a java class gets loaded, does it load the class only referenced (but not instantiated) in this class as well? I find its not loading until the referenced class gets instantiated or any static field is assigned a value. However, I learnt that this behavior varies JVM to JVM. Is it true?

Comment: Read the Java Language specification and the JVM specification to learn the deep intricacies of class loading.  The question is too broad for StackOverflow and already well documented elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are these two overloaded methods to load class.

```
loadClass(name, resolve);
loadClass(name);
```

Here resolve is a boolean flag and when it is true, it will resolve all the referenced classes also. When it is false it doe's not load referenced classes.

Note that for any class you will load, the resolve variable will always be true. It is only when the system is recursively calling loadClass() that it may set this variable false because it knows the class it is asking for is already resolved.

```
Here, loadClass(name); calls loadClass(name, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes are only loaded when they get **used**.

It is pretty easy to make your own experiments to "prove" that, by having the ClassLoader print what it is doing; see [here](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/01/when-and-how-a-java-class-is-loaded-and-initialized/) for how that works.

I *think* that this is a **specified** property of the JVM; meaning: all JVMs should do it that way (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html) for details).

And you see - anything else would not make sense. Some class *A* might reference 10, 20 other classes. Would you really want to load all of those classes when *A* is loaded? And all the 10, 20 classes that those references of A are referencing to?! Without knowing if you will ever need them?!